# bashをログインシェルにして、fishを使いたい

Tags: bash, shellscript, fish

ログインシェルをbashにしてfishを起動したい場合、
.bashrcに

```
exec fish
```

と入力すればできるはずなのですが、fishが起動しません。
ホームディレクトリから

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

と入力しました。
何が間違えているのでしょうか。

- `bash` を実行すると `fish` に変わります
- ログインシェルを `bash` で行うと、`fish` は起動しません

Comment: ```fish```を入力すると、fishが立ち上がります。```bash```や```bash -l```は```The default interactive shell is now zsh.```と表示されます。```~/.bash_profile```には何も書かれていません。.bashrc内には```exec fish```と保存されてました。

Comment: 追記です。```bash_profile```がそもそも存在しませんでした。```cat .profile```すると、```eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"```と表示されます。

Comment: ```.bashrc```を書き直して再起動したところ、```bash```を実行するとfishに変わりました。```. ~/.bashrc```でも同様にfishが起動しました。

Comment: 解決したようで、よかったですね。どのように書き直すと解決したのかを回答として投稿して下さい。自己回答は推奨されています。

Comment: ログインシェルを’bash’で行うと、’fish’は起動しなかった。ログインシェルを’zsh’にして’~.zshrc’に’exec fish’と記入すると、’fish’が起動した。原因はよくわかっていない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ログインシェル時に動作が違うのは `~/.bashrc` が読まれないから

`~/.bashrc` は Bash がログインシェルとして起動された場合、デフォルトでは実行されません。対話シェルとしての Bash は、ホームディレクトリにあるファイルを、以下のルールで実行します。（ややこしいので、正確な動作は[マニュアル](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)を確認して下さい）

#### ログインシェルの場合

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`

がこの順番で探され、最初に見つかった物が実行されます。

#### 非ログインシェルの場合

`~/.bashrc` ファイルがあれば、ここからコマンドを読み込んで実行します

#### 対策

よって、ログインシェルの場合もコマンドを実行したいならば、例えば `~/.bash_profile` にも記述を追加する必要が有るということです。別のシェルを起動するようなコードは、対話シェルの時のみ実行させたいことでしょう。その場合は例えば下のように場合分けできます。

```bash
case $- in
    *i*)
        # 対話シェル（インタラクティブ）
        # ...
        ;;
    *)
        # 非対話シェル
        # ...
        ;;
esac
```

`. ~/.bashrc` などとして別のファイルを丸々読み込むことで、設定を一箇所にまとめることもあります。

Comment: `~/ .bashrc`や`~/ .bash_profile`などがどのような挙動で動くのか説明していただきありがとうございます。わからないことがあれば、まずはマニュアルを読もうと思います。