# wsl2にてdenoの環境構築がうまくいできません。

Tags: linux, wsl, deno

**困っていること**
公式やブログを参考に環境構築をしようとしているのですがうまいこといきません。

**やったこと**
1，curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh

2,　出てくる案内通りに以下のexportの2行をbashrcに追加

```
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bashrc (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/home/xxx/.deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

3，bashrcを確認。以下のものを確認済み。

```
~~
export DENO_INSTALL="/home/xxx/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
~~~
```

4，deno --versionを確認

**現状**
ここまでやって、コマンドプロンプトを閉じてまたdeno --versionをやると、以下みたいな感じになります。

```
deno --version

Command 'deno' not found, did you mean:

  command 'reno' from deb python3-reno (2.11.2-2build1)
  command 'xeno' from deb xenomai-system-tools (2.6.4+dfsg-1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

**参考にしたもの**
[DENO公式](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.2/getting_started/installation)

[deno qiita記事](https://qiita.com/azukiazusa/items/8238c0c68ed525377883)

Comment: コマンドを実行している画面を開き直してから `deno` コマンドを実行するとどうなりますか？ / 設定ファイル (.bashrc) に記述はしたけど、読み込んでいないのでコマンドが見つからないように見えます。

Comment: 関連？: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/91605/3054

Comment: cubickさん　　コマンドを実行しているコマンドプロンプトを一旦消して、再び開き、denoを打ち込むと、”現状”と同じものが出ました。記述はしたけど読み込んでいないと言うのは、"
$ source ~/.bashrc"　をやったか？ということでしょうか？

Comment: miyさん　見てみます。